# How to pass params from div to single page component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have such code on different pages:

```
<div id="contact-us" class="section md-padding bg-grey">
        <div id="contact"></div>

        <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
</div>
```

I have main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Contact from './Contact.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#contact',
    render: h => h(Contact)
})
```

And Contact.vue with a template

I want to know from which page component was used. So I need to pass param from div like `<div id="contact" page="main"></div>` . How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass params from div to single page component in Vue.js?

You can't pass params from a div since it's a html tag and a not custom component, you should define your own component that accepts the properties you want to pass.

So first you should define your component and define the property is allow to receive, then you use your component, take a look to the below example, and you may find more information about passing props [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props).

```js
Vue.component('your-component', {
  props: ['property'],
  template: '<h3>{{ property }}</h3>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <your-component :property="'Hello props'" />
</div>
```

Example using Single File Component structure.

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <ChildComponent :property="propValue" />
</template>


<script>
  import childComponent from './childComponent.vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      ChildComponent: childComponent
    },
    data() {
      return {
        propValue: 'Hello prop'
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

Children component:

```
<template>
  <h3>{{ property }}</h3>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['property'] // You can add more properties separeted by commas
}
</script>
```

Comment: I know. But I think it is a very bad way to define template in a string. I need a Single File Component.

Comment: Ok let me add an example with Single File Component structure.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case we again need to create SFC for every page. We can't use it on html pages.

Comment: Mmmm, the last example is actually a SFC, take a look to the official docs https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: Well, ok. I understand that in vue to create reusable components I should only write template in a string. Or create many SFC to different pages.

Comment: Yeah, it is SFC. But it doesn't solve my problem. I need to create many SFCs for each page to determine from which page request was send.